# Will a github token leak when running github actions

Tags: github, github-actions, .git-folder

I'm running Github actions workflow in a private repo, and it pushes changes in a public repo. I'm providing my GitHub token in the private repo for the workflow github actions. Will my token leak in my public repo .git?

Can somebody clarify this? I'm don't have knowledge of security things :(

Comment: are you configuring your secret as an Action Secret or are you pushing it to the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Automatic token authentication](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication) page uses a `GITHUB_TOKEN` secret, which should, as its name suggests, remains... a secret.

> At the start of each workflow run, **GitHub automatically creates a unique** `GITHUB_TOKEN` secret to use in your workflow.
> You can use the `GITHUB_TOKEN` to authenticate in a workflow run.
>
> The `GITHUB_TOKEN` secret is a GitHub App installation access token.
> You can use the installation access token to authenticate on behalf of the GitHub App installed on your repository.
> [The token's permissions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#permissions-for-the-github_token) are limited to the repository that contains your workflow.

So you should not need to use your own GitHub token, only the one generated by GitHub Action.